# is it possible override key value if using allOf?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm new to openAPI 3.0 specs and wanted to know if one can override the key `status` to `somestatus`?

```
Response:
  type: object
  properties:
    status: # want to override this key
      type: number
      format: int32
    timestamp:
      type: string
      format: date-time
ApiResponse:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Response'
    - type: object
  properties:
    message:
      type: string
      format: string
```

The Response has a field status so will ApiResponse as it extends it. Now can I override the key value `status` to `something else` in ApiResponse. 
Our Schema is pretty evolved so just came up with this generic example. I think it's not possible but I still wanted to ask it out.

Comment: Override meaning change the key name or data type?

Comment: key name i.e. from `status` to `someOtherStatus`